# HttpURLConnection wire logging in Android

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to get all the headers for request/response in my logcat. Seems there is no easy way with `HttpURLConnection` as it is with `org.apache.http`.

According to [this blog](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-debug-HttpURLConnection-problem.html) you can do:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
```

Seems this was removed from Android implementation for `HttpURLConnection`.
Is there any easy way to sniff requests/responses on logcat?

Comment: Anyone ? there must be an easy way...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? accessing the headers for each request can be easily done as pointed out by @Rhand, but it seems there is more to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can easily do yourself:

```
private static void logConnection(HttpURLConnection httpConnection) throws IOException {
    int status = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    Log.d("logConnection", "status: " + status);
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : httpConnection.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("logConnection", header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: With Your code you'll log only the Response Code and Header. The request will be consumed and is not accessible anymore

Comment: This is just the logging, you'd call this from the method where you process the request. e.g open connection, log response code (by calling logConnection()), process response.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37525989/11845778
Though, you would still need to do the logcat part. This just gets the response as JSON.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure it is possible with standard HttpURLConnection on Android. Therefore it is easy to achieve using OkHttp library:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

OkHttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.url("http://android.com");

client.newCall(requestBuilder.build()).execute();
```